# SQL Server Join meaning

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

When you write a join statement, and just use 'join' does that default to any join? Or is join also a type of join statement?

```
select * from a join b on a.c = b.c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`join` is the same as `inner join`.

Comment: that's what the docs alluded to just wanted to make sure thanks!